# Typedef with template functions

Tags: c++, c++11

Say I have a template function in namespace A. I also have another namespace B. There is a template function declared in namespace A, which is defined as

```
template<typename T, typename U>
void f(T a, U b);
```

Now in namespace B, I would want to declare a specialized type of the template function. I was thinking if I could `typedef` the template function so it is declared in namespace B as

```
void f(int a, double b);
```

without actually implementing the function calling the template function. As there is a way to declare new typenames with specific template parameters, shouldn't there be a way to do that with functions aswell?
I tried different methods to achieve it, but it didn't quite work out.

So is there already a way in C++ to redeclare the function with given template parameters without actually implementing a new function? If not, is it somehow achievable in C++11?

It would be a neat feature to have since it would make the purpose of the function more clear and would be syntactically better :)

Edit: So one could write:

```
using A::f<int, double>;
```

in B namespace and the function would show up with those template parameters

Comment: After a glance, does this help? http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#template-alias

Comment: Not quite sure if it does, since it seems the current version of visual c++ doesn't support using syntax(?). At least for me it just outputted loads of syntax errors

Comment: The compiler has to support the feature as well. I don't think GCC does yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `using`:

```
namespace A {
    template <typename T> void f(T);
    template <> void f<int>(int);    // specialization
}

namespace B {
    using ::A::f;
}
```

You can't distinguish between the *specializations* like that (since `using` is only about *names*), but it should be enough to make the desired specialization visible.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap an inline function:

```
namespace A
{
    template<typename T, typename U>
    void f(T a, U b);
};

namespace B
{
    inline void f(int a, double b) { A::f(a,b); }
};
```

See this question:

[C++11: How to alias a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864125/c11-how-to-alias-a-function)