# Alias function template

Tags: c++, c++17

I want to be able to do the equivalent of this:

```cpp
template <class T>
void foo(int i=42) {
  // ... do stuff and use T for something ...
}

using ifoo= foo<int>; // <-- This is the part I am looking for

int main() {
  ifoo();
}
```

Is there any way to do something like this?

Comment: `auto ifoo = &foo<int>;`? AFAIK, there are no aliases for functions (nor function template instances) but you still can store a pointer to a function.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat "there are no aliases for functions". A function pointer is exactly what one would expect from an alias, no?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I wouldn't dare to call a function pointer an "alias"... ;-) Maybe, I was too focused on alias like in `using` or `typedef`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Have a look at the Definition at the bottom of the question in [C++11: How to alias a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9864125/7478597). (I don't know whether it's correct or authoritative but this is what I had in mind.)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat You are right that it is not an alias. One obvious difference is that if `foo()` has default parameters, `ifoo()` will not. Maybe my example was to simple.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function pointer:

```
auto ifoo = &foo<int>;
```

Note that the `&` is optional (ie you can also write `auto ifoo = foo<int>;`). `auto` gets deduced as `void (*)()`.

Comment: I would mark it `const` or `constexpr`. Otherwise a call to it cannot be inlined and a function shouldn't be assignable either.

Comment: While this is good (and this is what I did in my code), `ifoo` doesn't inherit the default parameters of `foo`, so if it is declared as `foo(int i=42);`, I will have to call `ifoo` with a parameter

Comment: @Baruch in your question `foo` has no arguments. Anyhow, then I'd go for Mareks solution

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solutions are usually the best:

```cpp
void ifoo()
{
   foo<int>();
}
```

compiler should optimize this so `ifoo` and `foo<int>` just shares code.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a reference (alias) to the specific function.

```
auto& ifoo= foo<int>;
```

---

or alias the whole template (technically one-by-one)

```
template <typename T>
auto& fooT = foo<T>;
```

---

https://godbolt.org/z/nqbKfnfhe (with some more examples)

Comment: Interesting, `auto& fn = func;` works, but `auto& fn = &func;` does not.  (`auto const& fn = &func;` works for the second case.)

Comment: @Eljay `&func` is a non-`const` pointer prvalue. A non-`const` reference cannot be bound to a prvalue. In `auto& fn = func;` the initializer is a lvalue to which the reference binds directly. (No implicit function-to-pointer conversion takes place.)

Comment: @user17732522 • Thank you, I get it.  I'm just so used to function pointer decay that it startles me when there's a difference.

Comment: @Eljay you can also bind to rvalue reference `auto&& f = &func`

Comment: or `void (*&&f)() = &func` (in both case it's binding to a pointer to the function)